# Discriminated union and redefining property type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I'm having a following issue in typescript 3.9.7. Given the following code:

```
type A = {
  type: string;
  cellRendererParams: any;
  filter: string;
};

type C = {
   type: 'yy';
   cellRendererParams: {
   test: any;
  };
};


type Combined = A | C;

const u: Combined = {
  type: 'yy',
  cellRendererParams: { test: 'asd'}
};
```

I would expect that typescript will complain about `cellRendererParams` but it doesn't. I assume it happens because it is able to fall back to `A` type. I could change the type to

```
type A = {
  type: string;
  cellRendererParams: never;
  filter: string;
};
```

And it will work but I still want to leave the user an option to create A and specify `cellRendererParams`, unfortunately never prevents that. Also, I'm able to use `filter`  property for some reason.

Is there an easy solution to this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKVSQFxQM7ACcBLAOwHMBuNKAYwgBt6AlCEgEwgM4AUBDA3gFtcOXiRBV0AMyL1gnHPmLkqAXyopM0AMIJk1DOAg4A5CBAnJ6OoxbtOPfkJH70GCPlHir6lL5SaRlDaAPaCAEakEGx6cAA%20wRo0IST4UACuOKERUTGIqOhapuYmADTUNsysHFwEfALCOEjunlAmvLhsJqp%20FEA)

Comment: Does it work for you https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQDwBUB8cC8cDeo4FySwBccAzmAE4CWAdgOYDc+hAxjADacBKMdAExhVhABQCGVcQFtyZFCxABfRaGLwAwllysC6sgHIIEA4sJwO3PoOFjJMuTpDnzYGJTLi6EM4RWh-EFA1aE0Ae2kAI3oYAVQMbGR0OAAfOA1VEDYwuko4AFcyDQjoulikSlpGVLg6fKjhBKdXUMNjAwAaXQsuXn4hESoJKVlDcXIBccmJgzgAejm4MIBrAMzQbNywAsL0kpi42vrIxu08Z0J9OCMTLouCSz6bQeGHMYmpqdmFuGEqMKoayAA ?

Comment: That's not really descriminated now, is it? "yy" is still assignable to string

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not complain"? `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ test: any; }'` errors as expected. But, when you specify the `filter` property, the error goes away exactly because of what is mentioned by Roberto above: as `yy` is assignable to string, and `cellRendererParams` in type `A` is any, it is the union member that matches the `{ type: "yy", cellRendererParams: "asdasdasd", filter: "some filter" }`.

Comment: @OlegValter I've edited, it should be {test:"asd"}. I understand the reasons why it works this way but is there a way to say, if type is string then cellParams is any, and if it's 'yy' then it's of type {test:any} ? Without using generics and conditional types

Comment: @MistyK ah, now it's clearer, thanks (although, as I suppose you understand, the reason why is the same as the above). Well, given the constraint "no generics and no conditionals", I would incline to say no, but still not sure what are you trying to achieve here. Take a look [at the playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOaJMm) - isn't the behavior as expected? Or do you want `cellRendererParams` to be "any, but not { test: any }"?

Comment: @OlegValter There are two issues. Please check this playground, I left my comments + ultimate goal: https://tsplay.dev/mL94KW

Comment: @MistyK - thanks! Hm, seems like you have two *separate* problems (btw, you have a small typo in the playground - shouldn't `ultimateGoal` be `Combined[]`). If I read the playground correctly, the first one is "allow one and only one property in `cellRendererParams` if type is `C`". This is hard as (which you are likely aware of) TS does not do excessive property checks here - the type is not an object literal. Thus, you can specify whatever else as long as the `test` property is present (as, for example, `{ test: "abc", other: "def" }` is a subtype of `{ test: "abc" }`). [1/2]

Comment: @OlegValter Yep, it's a typo.First one is clear, will be hard to achieve but what about ultimate goal? Is it possible to define a list of objects, and cellRendererParams will be inferred based on 'type' property?

Comment: [2/2] I am not even sure it is possible since restricting to one and only property *without* a type parameter would require an `Exclude<string, "test">` union, which is, to my knowledge, impossible, since the result of this is just a `string`. As for the second problem, can you confirm if you want to disallow top-level property `filter` iff `type` is `yy` to avoid falling back to type `A`? Then you need to do something to `type: string;` in it, because even if you try `filter: never` in type `C`, assignability of `yy` to string renders the constraint moot.